# Background image in IE7 doesn't appear on load

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I know the heading looks like the issue might have been asked already but after searching a lot, I couldn't find my answer so I am asking this.
I found at several other places also but I couldn't find a suitable solution. I think, I can be helped here.

I have an input type textbox field, I am adding a div around it dynamically using javascript. This div has one class="errorFieldIcon" attribute. I have this class definition in my css file.

When I try to debug it in IE7 developer tool, I find the code for this class is reflected in Style tab. But, when I see the page the style effect is not reflected on the page. I have noticed that if I just go to developer tool and uncheck/check any of the CSS property in Style tab, I am able to see this image.

This is quite surprising for me as I have noticed such an issue first time.Whenever page is loaded it doesn't show image/icon but when I uncheck or check any of the CSS propert, it starts displaying image.

**My class code is**

```
.errorFieldIcon{
    background-image: url("../images/IcoMessageError.gif");
    height: 16px;
    left: -18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    width: 16px;
}

.errorFieldIcon {
    background-image: url("../img/ico_error.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**Code**

```
<TD class="DefaultFontBlack errorHighlight" vAlign=center colSpan=2 align=left>
 <DIV id=etvErrIcon class=errorFieldIconOwner>
  <DIV class=errorFieldIcon>
  </DIV>
 </DIV>
 <INPUT value=123# type=text name=SITE_DK_NUMBER_RULE>
</TD>
```

if you need more info, I can provide. Since I am running it in local I am unable to provide link. But I feel this description should be sufficient.

Comment: why you have declared two images as background on same element ?

Comment: You have defined background image for a class two times so ie will only choose style which is declared in bottom of your style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

IE7 is very "pickie" when it come to incorrect HTML.
A lot of errors could be corrected if you use correct HTML, stopping the browser going in to [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

User lowercase HTML, quote your attributes, use a doctype.

Check your CSS, 2 images set for the same element/class, so based on your provided CSS, you will only see the last one:

```
.errorFieldIcon {
  background-image: url("../img/ico_error.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

In your CSS, is there a `position: relative` for `.errorFieldIconOwner`, maybe it is because of the absolute positioning, that you not see the image?